# Trying to remove "ZCTA" from rows

Tags: r, zipcode

I am trying to extract only the zip code values from my imported ACS data file, however, the rows all include "ZCTA" before the 5 digit zip code. Is there a way to remove that so just the 5 digit zip code remains?

Example:

[image: Image of data frame with ZCTA and Zip]

I tried using strtrim on the data but I can't figure out how to target the last 5 digits. I image there is a function or loop that could also do this since the dataset is so large.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064).

Answer (score 2):

To remove "ZCTA5":

```
gsub("ZCTA5", "", df$zip) # df - your data.frame name
```

or

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(df$zip,"ZCTA5","")
```

To extract ZIP CODE:

```
str_sub(df$zip,-5,-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few others for fun:

```r
#option 1
stringr::str_extract(df$zip, "(?<=\\s)\\d+$")

#option 2
gsub("^.*\\s(\\d+)$", "\\1", df$zip)
```